# very simple, javascript arrays syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a very simple JS Arrays question, my simple canvas game has been behaving differently when I replaced one block of code with another. Could you look them over and see why they are functionally different from one another, and maybe provide a suggestion? I may need these arrays to have 20+ items so I'm looking for a more condensed style.

There's this one, which is short enough for me to work with, but doesn't run well:

```
var srd=new Array(1,1,1);
var sw=new Array(0,0,0);
var sang=new Array(0,0,0);
var sHealth=new Array(20,20,20);
```

And then there's the original one, which is longer but works fine:

```
var srd = new Array();
srd[1] = 1; 
srd[2] = 1; 
srd[3] = 1; 
var sw = new Array();
sw[1] =0; 
sw[2] =0; 
sw[3] =0; 
var sang = new Array();
sang[1] = 0; 
sang[2] = 0; 
sang[3] = 0;
var sHealth = new Array();
sHealth[1] = 20; 
sHealth[2] = 20; 
sHealth[3] = 20;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this....in Arrays values are stored as such that first one is at 0 and so on.
so 1st value will be accessed as this...

```
 var x = abc[0]; //first value of array abc being assigned to x.
```

**Do this** (you see i actually read your question and this is what you like)

```
 var srd=['',1,1,1];
 var sw=['',0,0,0];
 var sang=['',0,0,0];
 var sHealth=['',20,20,20];
```

you can declare an array(object) in javascript like this

var x = [];         -------------Literal - its a shortcut provided by JS to quickly declare something as an Array.

var x = new Array; --Array **constructor**

Things to look up regarding

**literal**

- object literal
- proto
- word new
- function object
- function property prototype

You can also do these:

`var x=1,y=2,
z=3,
f;`

`var b = something || {}; \\become a copy of object called something if it's not there then become an empty object.`

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are zero-indexed in JavaScript. The first element is `0`, not `1`:

```
var srd = new Array();
srd[0] = 1; 
srd[1] = 1; 
srd[2] = 1;
```

Also, you may want to use the more common array constructor:

```
var srd = [1, 1, 1];
```

I have a feeling that you may be assuming that the first element is `1` instead of `0`, which is why the first version doesn't work while the second one does.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about that, always run into that issue :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one starts the arrays at index 0 and the other one starts at index 1

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about that, always run into that issue :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation, but it's likely because of arrays being 0-indexed. In your first block of code, each number is offset by one index spot from the second block. The first one is equivalent to:

```
var srd = new Array();
srd[0] = 1; 
srd[1] = 1; 
srd[2] = 1;
```

in the way you wrote it for the second block.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about that, always run into that issue :)